# Magento 2 How can I show custom options on cart page?

Tags: magento2

I want to show custom product option in cart page magneto 2

```
echo $block->getLayout()->getBlock('product.info.options')->setProduct($product)->toHtml();
```

I got this type of error following :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setProduct() on boolean in /var/www/html/dev/gavin/albanyappliances/app/design/frontend/Albany/default/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/item/default.phtml:116
```

Comment: In `checkout/cart` page?

Comment: Yes.... checkout/cart page

Comment: Magento by default provide custom option in `checkout/cart` page.